# UICollectionViewController can't reach cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to change the text of my label inside an UICollectionViewCell. The ViewCell class is linked to the cell, the outlets are set and in the viewController its registered by

```
// Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

and in cellForItemAt...

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
```

but I can't access the label. Same problem with an imageView. If I tried to set the text with:

```
cell.hund.text = "bla"
```

the label "hund" is known but it throws that the label is nil.

Thanks Tom

ImageCollectionVC

```
import UIKit
private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

class ImageCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

var listOfImages = [Int: KKImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    listOfImages = xmlParseImageSource()
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfImages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    let imgUrl = listOfImages[indexPath.row]?.imagePreviewUrl

    do {
        let bindData = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl!)
        let img = UIImage(data: bindData)

        cell.hund.text = "bla"

        //cell.img.image = img
        //cell.img.image = UIImage(data: bindData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return cell
}
}
```

ImageCollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var hund: UILabel!  
}
```

Comment: Please share the complete viewController code that includes the collectionView in and the ImageCollectionViewCell code to check what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a xib for the UICollectionViewCell if yes make sure you have the outlets connected properly.

Comment: @rameez no, I've got no xib.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas in awake from nib just initialize your UIImageView and UILabel and add them to the cell, it should work :)

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   // Initialization code, you obviously need to set the frames/constraints as per your requirement

   img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
   hund = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
   self.addSubview(img)
   self.addSubview(hund)
}
```

In case you are using an xib don't register the class instead use the nib registration which should be:

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ImageCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier )
```

Comment: thanks rameez, but how can I initialize them? In the interface builder? Sorry I'm very new in swift and my 1200 pages book of swift doesn't tell me how, respectively I can't find it :)

Comment: it doesn't work. And btw I can't understand why I should create a new label. I'd add it in the interface builder. The subclass of the cell is set to ImageCollectionViewCell. I'll try this in a new project to check if it works then.

Comment: You said your cell doesn't have an xib.

Comment: Ok if you have an xib make sure you have set the outlets properly you don't need to intiliaze the label and image in that case.

Comment: sorry, I'm German and I have to translate your sentences for me. Now I know what xib is. Like you can see in my question, the outlets are set.

Comment: use the registerNIb method check my answer it should work.

Comment: Then I get this error
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/studio/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/38619258-0027-49E1-B951-B40410074DBF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8E4F0DB0-F5A9-4CD1-8D7A-108702983D5F/KarmaKarakta InSide.app> (loaded)' with name 'ImageCollectionViewCell''`

Comment: Does the xib and UICollectionViewCell files have the same name? Also make sure you have correctly spelled the .xib file while registering it.

Comment: yes, I can't understand it. I can access to the label in the ViewCell with cell.hund.... but on running its nil.

Comment: I have a repo [here](https://github.com/rameeznkhan/SampleCollectionViewFlowLayout) please check

Comment: wow, thanks for your help. I'll check it out and try to adopt it.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you. Now I know to handle a custom cell. Thats so easy, but nobody told me before how I use it. :)